# Verificar la conexion de un en selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo un aplicativo en selenium de c# pero durante la ejecucion puede ocurrir que se quede sin conexion a internet. entonces lo hice de esta manera:

```
try{
    driver2.Navigate().Refresh();
}catch(Exception ex){
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Perole quito el internet fisicamente al equipo la pagina se refresca, aparece timeOut y pasa por el try pero no lanza ninguna excepcion.
¿Como hago para capturar ese error de que no hay conexion con la pagina.?

Comment: Si no se presenta excepción alguna, es porque no hay. Usted menciona: `aparece timeOut` ¿el timeout no es suficiente prueba de que no hay conexión?. Si tiene mas código, le recomiendo [edit] la pregunta y agregar este código y la descripción de los errores que tenga.

Comment: Si pero el timeOut lo detecto yo como usuario y el objetivo es que software se de cuenta de que no hay conexion y lance una excepcion.

Answer (score 0):

¿A qué te refieres que habrá cortes de internet? ¿Es algo que es habitual o simplemente es por precaución de que se pueda dar esa situación?
Si te quedas sin internet, Selenium intentará la instrucción y si pasa el tiempo del timeout y el driver no ha recibido respuesta, te lanzará una excepción TimeOut (cuyo tiempo puedes modificar).
Por cierto, ¿a qué te refieres con que el timeout lo detectas tú?
Un saludo.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/350471)